# Use of CacheLoader and CacheWriter in Gemfire

Tags: gemfire

I have a client server topology in gemfire. I want  to use cacheLoader and cacheWriter to synchronize my in memory gemfire cache with RDBMS database oracle.
Where  exactly I should plug in these cacheLoader and cacheWriter..in the client regions or server regions or I can choose any one of these?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the server regions. There's no reason why the client app should depend on an RDBMS in this case.

Comment: Actually I have the servers created from gfsh console using cache.xml file and the client from a spring application using spring data gemfire....now currently I have plugged in the loader and writer to the client region in the spring context xml...the loaders and writers are using crudRepository of spring data JPA to connect to database to load and write to RDBMS...If I change the loader and writer to be plugged in to the server region then I can not make use of crudRepository of spring data JPA.